# Typescript: typeof check in list item does not work

Tags: typescript

I have this code in TypeScript:

```
type NameValue = { name: string; value: string };
type MixedStuff = NameValue | string;

function stripTwoChars(stuffs: MixedStuff[]): string {

    let stuffZero = stuffs[0];
    return (typeof stuffZero === "string" ?
        stuffZero.slice(0, 2) :
        stuffZero.name.slice(0, 2)); // This works fine

    return (typeof stuffs[0] === "string" ?
        stuffs[0].slice(0, 2) : // Here error: no slice on NameValue
        stuffs[0].name.slice(0, 2)); // Here error: no name on string
}
```

So, as you can see in the function, first I save the first list item in a variable and then do a typeof check on that, which works fine.

But if I directly do the typeof on the first list item, the type check does not work.

Is this a bug or why would this supposed to be that way?

Comment: ah, thanks. does not solve the actual issue, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is by design, type-guards on array access expression were considered but rejected. See discussion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11483)

> Declined due to performance reasons. Since it should almost always be possible to write `const j = list[i]` instead, this shouldn't be too burdensome.